# ASP.NET Core 3.0 MVC persistence

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-3.0

I'm developing an ASP.NET Core MVC web app. My requirements is login and logout functionality. How to do the persistence? I would like to develop with identity extension. Please guide me how to implement proper way.

The below `IdentityExtension` and `GenericUser` both class are used my previous ASP.NET MVC framework project. In a similar way, I would like to create the ASP.NET Core 3.0 MVC app.

```
public static class IdentityExtension
{
    public static GenericUserIdentity ToGenericUserIdentity(this IIdentity identity)
    {
        var cookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];
        var ticketInfo = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(cookie.Value);
        return new GenericUserIdentity(ticketInfo);
    }
}
```

The class `GenericUserIdentity` inherited from `IIdentity` similar way shall I create `GenericUserIdentity : ClaimsIdentity` or should I use same `IIdentity` - please give any example.

```
namespace Tmmmt.Persistance
{
    [Serializable]
    public class GenericUser
    {
        public string RoleName { get; set; }
        public int UserID { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }       
    }
    
    [Serializable]
    public class GenericUserIdentity : IIdentity
    {
        private GenericUser genericUser;
        private FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket;
        
        public GenericUserIdentity(FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket)
        {
            var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
            var reader = new JsonTextReader(new StringReader(ticket.UserData));
            genericUser = serializer.Deserialize<GenericUser>(reader);
            this.ticket = ticket;
        }

        public string AuthenticationType
        {
            get { return "Custom"; }
        }

        public bool IsAuthenticated
        {
            get { return ticket != null; }
        }

        public string Name
        {
            get { return genericUser.UserName; }
        }

        public string RoleName
        {
            get{return genericUser.RoleName;}
        }
        
        public int UserID
        {
            get { return genericUser.UserID; }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would start here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: Thank for the update the link will help to me even though can you see above sample code. @Valuator